# How to turn off the auto pop-up of Salesforce-CLI window everytime I save (deploy source to Org) in VSCode DX

Tags: apex, vs-code

I'm using VSCode for my salesforce development and I installed the Salesforce CLI integration plugin and Salesforce extension pack.
**Every time I save a source code which gets deployed to Org automatically**, *(I set that option in the JSON config file)*, **the Salesforce-CLI window on the bottom of VSCode pops up and I have to close it manually**.
**I was wondering if there's a way to turn that off.** I can still open the Salesforce-CLI window manually if I need to.

- *VSCode version 1.36.1*
- *Extension Pack version 46.7.0*

Update on 8/22, this behavior is still the same with the latest versions:

- VSCode version 1.70.1
- Extension Pack version 55.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `"show-cli-success-msg"` parameter in your settings.json.
According to the plugin:

```
Salesforcedx-vscode-core: Show-cli-success-msg 
Specifies whether status messages for Salesforce CLI commands run using
the VS Code command palette will appear as pop-up information messages
(true) or as status bar messages (false).
```

Here my own settings.json:

```
"salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that setting just changes the pop-up notification behavior. What I'm looking for is the integrated CLI window or section (not sure what it's called but the same one as the integrated terminal with ctr+`). I would like to disable that from popping up on every save or deploy resource to the server.

Comment: @Bahman.A Same here, did you find any workaround?

Comment: Hi @Rajendra Singh Nagar no I have not found a workaround yet.

Comment: Also looking for a workaround here